# DataGridCloumnHeaderCheckbox style

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPF datagrid. Using the following style I am applying checkbox to one of the columheader.

```
<Style x:Key="TestDataColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="chkbxCheckAll" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckAll, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=TestDataScreen}" Click="chkbxCheckAll_Click">

                            </CheckBox>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Control.Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFC2E3F6" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.53" Color="#FFF1FBFD" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF2FAFD" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="#FFDADADA" />
<Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="1,0,1,1" />
<Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="26" />
<Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

The problem I am facing is, I can see the checkbox in columnheader but columnheader background color is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a border around the checkbox like this

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
  <CheckBox x:Name="chkbxCheckAll" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckAll, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=TestDataScreen}" 
          Click="chkbxCheckAll_Click">
  </CheckBox>
</Border>
```

**Edit:**

If you make the background black and set the background of the CheckBox to TemplateBinding Background you will notice that a littlebit of the checkbox is getting black. This has to do with the build-in style of the CheckBox.

Comment: Glad it worked, however this is just a very little-info example. You could also extend BorderThickness, BorderBrush, etc. Good luck.

Comment: I have one more question... I couldn't understand the reason behind it. Can you please give me some insight to it?

Comment: Well, TemplateBinding connects to the Property it's pointed to. So if you set TemplateBinding in any control in your controltemplate to Background, than it use the property you set in the style. The style however only holds the fallbackvalues in case you don't manually set the background in the control you actually use. The reason why the Checkbox does not do what you want is because somewhere in the Default Style for the CheckBox (embedded in the .NET framework) the `{TemplateBinding Background}` is only connected to the little markerbox and even there not very visible.

Comment: Example: `<Button Background="Black" Content="Hello"> <Button.Style> <Style TargetType="Button"> <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/> <Setter Property="Template> <Setter.Value> <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button"> <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"> <ContentPresenter/> </Border> </ControlTemplate> </Setter.Value> </Setter> </Style> </Button.Style> </Button>` This is a black button. Remove the `Background="Black"` and it will have a white background a defined as fallback/default in the style. Check out this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks a ton :) :) You explained it in really a nice way. Cheers mate :)

Comment: Silvermind, one more question, do you think my discussion or question is invalid? Am I doing technically something worng? Someone marked my question down :( :(

Comment: The question could be misread like, it's not working. Help me. But you should look into styling and templating more I guess. However it can be quite confusing with styles sometimes so I understand your question.

Comment: Sure. I will do that. Actually I am a C# programmer. New to WPF. I am learing it :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, maybe Background was originally bounded to something in the default Template which you override.
Maybe you can try fixing that by adding a TemplateBinding for Background on the CheckBox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkbxCheckAll" ... Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

By the way, this is untested.

Comment: Hey Xiao, I tried the solution given by you, but it isn't working :( :(

Comment: Are you able to see BorderBrush and BorderThickness correctly set right now?

Comment: I doubt it, only the style for checkbox is applied. After that nothing is applied.